# Change font size with Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to change my font size which is not equal to 9 to 9.
But it pops out "Compile Error: Expected Expression".

```
Sub FindReplaceStyle()

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting

    With .Font
        .Size <> 9
    End With

    .Format = True

    With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
        With .Font
            .Size = 9
        End With
    End With

    .Execute Forward:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, _
        FindText:="", ReplaceWith:=""
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2830554 : `<>` is an conditional operator, so you cannot use it without a conditional statement